# How do i fix recyclerview shows database entrys twice after new entry?

Tags: java, database, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

**My Code**

```
FloatingActionButton button;
        button = findViewById(R.id.floatbtn);
        if (button != null) {
            button.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(android.view.View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Userlist.this, AddTextActivity.class));
                    recyclerView.removeAllViews();
                    recyclerView.removeAllViewsInLayout();
                }
            });
        }

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userList);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Messages");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Text text = dataSnapshot.getValue(Text.class);
                    list.add(text);

                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

How do i fix recyclerview shows database entrys twice after new entry

I try to delete to remove all Views when Activity is closing. This didnt work.
Can you help me with this problem?
Why is this happening at all?

Comment: try to clear your list before adding items again like this if(list !+ null){list. clear list.add(text} else {list.add}

Comment: Have you tried to clear the list before updating it? Please respond using @AlexMamo